# Expanding do while condition in C++

Tags: c++

im a beginner starting to learn c++ i have a question.. Can i write scripts in do while loop i mean like this...

```
 //you type do then like 
 do{
    
         // your code here
    
    }while(condition{  //           <-- the question is here
 
then the code of the script


} ) closing Parenthesis and curly braces
```

yeah if you didn't understand that my question was that can i expand my condition in the while Parenthesis?? please answer because I'm learning C++ and I wanna improve.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to put in the condition? The condition is something that has to evaluate to a boolean expression

Comment: Call a function which can do a lot of processing, and then return a boolean `true` or `false`?

Comment: you can call a function inside that condition, and the function body can be as complex as you wish

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The condition after the `while` has to be an expression. That said: a function call is an expression as well as an immediately called lambda. Both of them provide a body where you can use every statement (inside the curly braces).

Comment: you can use functions to put scripts in the while condition , for example you can define a function 'isEmpty' which return boolean value and you can use it in your while condition.

Comment: A capturing lambda function as condition maybe?

Comment: C++ isn't usually called a *scripting language*, because it is compiled.  (It gets a little fuzzy because the popular scripting languages use a JIT to "compile" to bytecode and interpret the compiled bytecode.)  What kind of "scripts" do you want to do in the while condition loop?

Answer (score 7):

The `while` condition takes an *expression*. That includes things like variables (`foo`), operators (`1 + 2`), and function calls. But it excludes things like if statements and additional loops. If you need to do something complicated inside of a `while` block, you should put it in a function.

```
do {
  // ...
} while (should_continue(foo, bar));

bool should_continue(int foo, int bar) {
  // ... complicated code goes here ...
}
```

Technically speaking, in C++11 and onward, you can create and evaluate a lambda in the same line, allowing arbitrary statements in expression context, but this is not very readable and should generally be a sign that your code needs to be split up into more functions.

```
// Don't do this; your coworkers will despise you.
do {
  // ...
} while (([&]() {
  // ... complicated code goes here ...
})());
```

Some non-portable compiler extensions will also allow the syntax you suggested in the question, where you can just throw braces `{ ... }` with arbitrary statements in expression context. But, again, this is non-portable and not very readable code to begin with. So just write a function.